# Cycles GPU Render button is looking passive

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I am adding a image. Why i can't use this render?. I am using Windows 10 and AMD Radeon Software. My Blender versiyon is 2.79. I did install yesterday (27.06.18) I can't find a solution for AMD Radeon and I updated very soon (27.06.18).
And I am adding a photo for you can understand better.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html?#configuration):

> To enable GPU rendering, go into the User Preferences, and under the
>   System tab, select the Compute Device(s) to use. Next, for each scene,
>   you can configure to use CPU or GPU rendering in the Render
>   properties.
>
> OpenCL
>
> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. (We
>   only support graphics cards with GCN architecture 2.0 and above).
>
> If your video card is supported, download the latest drivers.

Comment: In the future, when quoting information from outside sources (manual, ect.) it is nice and a good practice to give attribution.

Comment: I did look which you are saying. I did chech my blender settings and i am adding a photo: https://i.hizliresim.com/oV394b.png
but nothıng is changed.. CPU render is very slow and not good enough... I am waiting your answer.